# Opacity only div in css

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Hello!</title>
  <style type="text/css">

    .class1{
      border:10px solid #000000;
      padding:5px;
      border-radius:12px;
      opacity: 0.1;
    }

    .class2{
      border:10px solid #000000;
      padding:5px;
      border-radius:12px;
      opacity: 100px !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="class1">
nghi
<div class="class2">
nghi2
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

In html file. I have 2 div. I want only opacity class1 not opacity div 2. I has use important property for div2  but it not effect. please help me take it thanks

Comment: I don't really understand your question but there is a mistake in `class2` it should be `opacity:100` instead of `opacity:100px`. Maybe that's the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
opacity: 100px !important;
```

Should be:

```
opacity: 100%;
```

or:

```
opacity: 1;
```

Also, you're missing a closing div tag. Did you mean for the divs to be separate, or one inside the other?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, you can't set opacity on a parent div and then set a different opacity (making it more opaque) on the child div

Answer (score 0):

Beside the syntactical error with the `px` and the fact that opacity goes from 0 to 1 (*and not 100*), If the `.div2` element is contained inside `.div1`  then you cannot do it..

The way your code is right now, where you only close one of the two divs it gets interpreted as the second div being inside the first one.

You might want to clarify/corerct this (*to make it valid as well*)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing Tag in the first DIV. When you fix it, should it for sure work.